# emails not sent from controller

Tags: joomla-3.x, jmail

I'm using a custom function in my controller to send emails, but the emails are not being sent.

My code:

```
function sendestimation()
{
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $email = $jinput->get('email');
    $contt = $jinput->get('contt');

    $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();

    $config = JFactory::getConfig();
    $sender = array( 
        $config->get( 'mailfrom' ),
        $config->get( 'fromname' ) 
    );

    $recipient = $email;

    $mailer->addRecipient($recipient);

    $body   = $contt;
    $mailer->isHtml(true);
    $mailer->Encoding = 'base64';
    $mailer->setBody($body);

    $send = $mailer->Send();
    if ( $send !== true ) {
        echo 'Error sending email: ';
    } else {
        echo 'Mail sent';
    }

}
```

I'm getting:

> Error sending email

so the email is not being sent and there is no email sent to my inbox.

I have tried Joomla's send email test and received:

> L'e-mail a bien été envoyé à support@myemail.com utilisant SMTP. Vérifier que vous avez reçu l'e-mail de test.
>
> *[The email has been sent to support@myemail.com using SMTP. Check that you have received the test e-mail.]*

Comment: What php version are you on and what exact Joomla version are you on? You should display all of the variables that you are generating/using to ensure that they all hold the intended values.  Beyond that basic diagnostic technique, this stream of chatter may help you progess: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=968659 and a blog post from toivo: http://talikka.com/joomla/finding-the-origin-of-cryptic-messages?view=article&id=17:how-to-debug-smtp-mail-in-joomla-3-6-5&catid=8:joomla and [another tutorial](https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/error-fix-joomla-smtp-connect-failed-error/)

Comment: After implementing Sharky's advice, can you tell us what you get if you write `JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(json_encode(['email' => $email, 'contt' => $contt, 'sender' => $sender, 'body' => $body, 'send' => $send]), 'notice');` at the bottom of your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `CMD` filter used by `Joomla\Input\Input::get()` strips out `@` character from the email address resulting in invalid address. Use a different filter like `STRING` to keep the character.

```
$email = $jinput->get('email', null, 'STRING');
```

Comment: You may want to mention something [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/15375/12352) so that researchers don't use an incorrect technique.

Comment: I tried the solution on that answer but still no email send
I did try send email test -> `L'e-mail a bien été envoyé à support@myemail.com utilisant SMTP. Vérifier que vous avez reçu l'e-mail de test.`